# PHP $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is empty when called from a Cron Tab

Tags: php

When I use the following code:

```
<?
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

I get a nice list off all server variables. However, when I enter the same code in a script, that is being called by a Cron Tab, a lot of variables are not listed. Also, the Document_root variable has no value.

I only have had this issue after moving to a different server. Do I need to tweak some server settings to avoid this?

Answer (score 7):

It's best not to rely on this variable as it isn't always set (just as you discovered).

Try setting and using a constant like this instead:

```
define('PUBLIC_PATH', '/var/www/path/to/public');

// OR something like:

define('PUBLIC_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/public');
```

Now use `PUBLIC_PATH` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: +1 - "not always set" can be expressed much more precisely though: It's not present when you run PHP through the Command Line Interface.

Comment: @Pekka that's an answer!

Comment: It's a good answer that let me understand the problem. But how to test productive code from command line without changing the code? Is there no option to set this like an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute via cron, are you just calling `php myscript.php` or are you accessing the php script via http? If you're executing directly via http then the apache variables (such as DocumentRoot) will not be available.