# Unable to get correct path in PHP due to server settings

Tags: php, path, server

I am not an expert on servers and one of my friends wanted to use some of my PHP scripts I wrote, but has a problem with his server and I was unable to find how to fix this.

Basically the problem is in generating paths to files.

In my script, I use the following variables to get the path:

```
$path = "/template/"; // path to the template folder
$baseURL = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path;
```

Then I include my pages for example like this:

```
include($baseURL."scripts/functions.php");
```

On my server, this works fine and when I tried to echo the baseURL parameter I get this:

```
/data/web/virtuals/104571/virtual/www/template/
```

However, on my friend´s server, it just throws `"PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function" - because I checked and the functions.php is not being loaded,`

When I tried echoing baseURL on my friend´s server, I got nothing.

So I tried viewing `phpinfo()` and interestingly, I did't find the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` there at all and the paths are just weird, the PHP error shows:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function convertT() in H:\webspace\hostings\kocher.es\hosting\www\meteotemplate\index.php on line 14
```

As I dont really understand servers so I dont know what this means, why it has that H:/ drive there and more importantly, how to fix this....

Here is the `phpinfo()` displayed:
http://kocher.es/meteotemplate/

If anyone knew how to fix this I would very much appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: This link might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131839/php-serverdocument-root-is-empty-when-called-from-a-cron-tab 1. you should't rely on the variable being set. 2. the variable $_SERVER is not present when you run it through the console interface. which might be the case in the other server configuration

Answer (score 0):

try `__DIR__`

example:

```
$basePath = __DIR__;
$templatePath = $basePath."/template/"; // path to the template folder

include($templatePath."/scripts/functions.php");
```

`__DIR__` will return file base directory and its different in different files which mean you must be careful from when will call it

Comment: well the problem is that I have the baseURL determined in like a global configuration file, which is included on each site and used to determine paths...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dirname(), pathinfo() and realpath() to determine the base path instead using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 0):

Please add document root path in httpd.conf file of apache

**Or** try _SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]